# How to do a count/calculation in a query

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to figure out a way to do the following sort of query..

I have a table that has a bit value and I want to calculate the percentage of records where the `bit =1`.

An example of the table would be ;

```
Job  Name   Active.
123  Smith.  1
123  Brown.  0
123  Jones.  1
123  Peters. 1
```

What I would like my result set to look like would be

```
Job Active
123. 75%
```

That being that for job '123' 75% (3 of the 4) are active...

The math part is easy, that being `3 / 4 * 100 = 75` but I have to first get the count value of the records with active = 1 and the count of all the records of 123.

There will be many jobs in the results so I would like to get back 1 record for each job with the calculate value for each job.

Any tips or samples on how to do this would be great...

Answer (score 5):

You can use aggregates and SUM(CASE in the same query.

```
SELECT
  Job,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Active=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Active,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Active=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Inactive,
  COUNT(*) AS Total,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Active=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 100.0 / COUNT(*) AS [%Active],
  SUM(CASE WHEN Active=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 100.0 / COUNT(*) AS [%Inactive]
FROM
  job
GROUP BY
  Job;
```

| Job | Active | Inactive | Total | %Active | %Inactive |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 3 | 1 | 4 | 75.000000000000 | 25.000000000000 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0d4394c3fe6a9e136786ddd2833d9565)*

Comment: What is the reason in additional CASEs? `100.0*SUM(Active)/COUNT(Active)` should be enough in this particular case...

Comment: @Akina just to show the user that they can be used more than once in the same query

Comment: Well, I see, you give general/common solution.